# How to avoid backslash while using Gson().toJson

Tags: java, json, string, rest, gson

So I have a rest model like Org.java , where I have one field of type String.

```
public class Org {
   private String employee;
   ...
}

public class Employee {
    private final String id;
     private final type;
     ....
}
```

While returning the API response I need to return the list of employee Object against the  `employe` field. So in my backend I get a list of `employee` Object.

`List <Employee> employeeList = getEmployeesList(..);`

**Note:** employeeList will never be null.

Then I tried to convert the `employeeList` to JSON to String and then set in the API model with the below approaches.

**Approach 1 :**

```
String employees= new Gson().toJson(employeeList);
org.setEmployee(employees);
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
String employees= (new Gson().toJson(employeeList)).replaceAll("\\","");
org.setEmployee(employees);
```

The problem is that a **backslash** is added before each double quote. I don't want that \ in front of the id , type and its values.

Could anyone please help me with this problem.

Currently what I am getting

```
{
"employee": [{\"id\":\"156543\",\"type\":\"employee\"}]
}
```

And what I want is below

```
{
"employee": [{"id":"156543","type":"employee"}]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurred because you are doing serialization twice. First step produces some double-quotations and the second step want to serialize double-quotations to `\"` character.

In this situation, I recommend you to make your final object and serialize it. For example, you should make some changes like below:

```
class Org {
   private List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

   public void add(Employee employee) {
       this.employee.add(employee);
   }
}

class Employee {
   private String id;
   private String type;

   Employee(String id, String type) {
      this.id = id;
      this.type = type;
   }
}

Org org = new Org();
org.add(new Employee("156543", "employee"));

String result = new Gson().toJson(org);
```

The result should be like as follow:

```
{"employee":[{"id":"156543","type":"employee"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Hossein. Will try the approach suggested by you.

Comment: I posted simple output for the solution.

Comment: Can't change the data type of employee from String to List. Thus in my above approaches was trying to convert employee list to String and finally was setting in the Org model instance. But good point on twice serialization. Will try to see if i can handle it in some way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the approach I was following earlier. But I solved my above issue by converting the data type of my **employee** filed from **String** to **Object** . By that way it accepts both String during request time and list of Object during response time.